# Listbox with objects passed to other listsboxes

Tags: c#, class, validation, parameter-passing, listboxitems

///TEAM PICKING APP to help Dota 2 drafts///

Objects on form:

1. heroListBox
2. team1ListBox
3. team2ListBox
4. addTeam1Button
5. addTeam2Button
6. labels placed below each team's listbox

I have a class called **Hero**. Each instance of a **Hero** has bools and a string for its name. The bools track attributes of that **Hero**'s abilities, for example if he has a ranged attack.

On my MainForm, there's a listbox with all of the available **heroes**. You select a **hero** then press one of two buttons: the button to send the object to *Team 1's listbox* or *Team 2's listbox*. Below each team's listbox are labels that keep count of that teams' abilities, for example how many **Heroes** in the team's listbox that have a ranged attack. That team's labels update every time you press that team's button.

I think I'm able to move an object from one list to another. But every time you press one of the two buttons that send, I cannot get the count to work:

```
public class Hero {
    public string Name;
    public bool IsInitiator;
    public bool IsTank;
    public bool IsNuker;
    public bool IsCarry;
    public bool IsPusher;       
    public bool IsRanged;
    public bool IsGreedy;
    public bool IsAOE;
    public bool IsDisabler;
    public bool IsRat;
    public Hero(string tempName){
        Name = tempName;
        IsInitiator = false;
        IsTank = false;
        IsNuker = false;
        IsCarry = false;
        IsPusher = false;       
        IsRanged = false;
        IsGreedy = false;
        IsAOE = false;
        IsDisabler = false;
        IsRat = false;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }


}


public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public int rcounter;
    public int dcounter;
    List<Hero> rHeroes = new List<Hero>();
    List<Hero> dHeroes = new List<Hero>();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
```

//just one example hero

```
        Hero Abbadon = new Hero("Abbadon");
        Abbadon.IsCarry=true;
        Abbadon.IsGreedy=true;
        Abbadon.IsTank=true;
        heroList.Items.Add(Abbadon);

        }
```

//add to team1 ... aka Radiant. Update those label texts!

```
    void addTeam1ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rcounter++;
        rHeroes.Add(heroList.SelectedItem as Hero);
        team1List.Items.Add(heroList.SelectedItem);
        heroList.Items.Remove(heroList.SelectedItem);

        for (int i = 0; i == rcounter; i++)
        {
            int rangedCounts = 0;
            if (rHeroes[i].IsTank == true){
                rangedCounts++;
            }
            radiantRangedLabel.Text = rangedCounts.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the label for the team count with every Hero, so it will always show 1 or 0 depending on the last hero checked in your loop...

Move the variable rangedCounts outside the loop